# Item selecionado no p:selectOneMenu chega nulo no listener

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-3.5

Tenho um p:selectOneMenu, com dados vindos do banco, dentro de uma p:dialog, junto com um p:messages e outros campos. Quero executar uma ação (Exibir algumas mensagens) ao selecionar determinada opção no p:selectOneMenu, mas recebo um nullPointerException porque o valor chega nulo no método listener do p:ajax. Já tentei usar o `onchange="submit();"` no p:selectOneMenu, o nullPointerException para, mas o método simplesmente não executa e nenhuma exception é mostrada, simplesmente não acontece nada.

**Dialog**

```
<p:dialog id="dialogRelato"
                  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
                  modal="true" header="Novo Relato"
                  widgetVar="dialogRelato" minHeight="40"
                  resizable="false">

            <p:messages id="menssagens" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

                <b>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Tipo de Relato: " />
                </b>
                <p:selectOneMenu style="height: 20px; width: 200px;"
                                 value="#{livroOrdemController.tipoRelatoSelecionado}"
                                 converter="tipoRelatoConverter">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{livroOrdemController.preencherComboTiposRelatos()}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{livroOrdemController.onSelectItemMenuChange()}" process="@this" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <br />
                <br />
            <p:calendar id="calendarDataOcorrencia"
                            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            locale="pt_BR"
                            showOn="button"
                            value="#{livroOrdemController.dataOcorrencia}">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{livroOrdemController.onDataOcorrenciaSelect()}"/>
                </p:calendar>
  </p:dialog>
```

**Método no Managed Bean**

```
public void onSelectItemMenuChange() {
   if(tipoRelatoSelecionado.getDescricao().equals("Acidentes e Danos")) {
       FacesUtils.mensErro("Teste Listener");
   }
}
```

**Converter**

```
@FacesConverter(value="tipoRelatoConverter")
public class TipoRelatoConverter implements Converter {

public TipoRelatoConverter() {
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String string) {
    if (string == null || string.equals("Selecione...")) {
        return null;
    }

    Long id = Long.parseLong(string);
    TipoRelato tipoRelato = new TipoRelato();
    tipoRelato.setIdTipoRelato(id);

    return tipoRelato;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if(object instanceof TipoRelato) {
        TipoRelato tipoRelato = (TipoRelato) object;

        return "" + tipoRelato.getIdTipoRelato();
    } 

    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("object:" + object + "of type:" + 
                object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type:br.org.web.entities.TipoRelato");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A `p:dialog` está dentro de um `form`?

Comment: Está sim. A página tem um form envolvendo várias p:dialogs e na hora do submit eu processo os campos que eu quero submeter

Comment: Já verificou se ao realizar o `change` seu converter está funcionando de acordo com o esperado? Por gentileza atualize a pergunta com o código do converter se possível

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o Converter

Comment: E ao debugar, ele retorna o resultado esperado, ou nem é chamado?

Comment: O converter é chamado sim. Ao debugar percebi que só a descrição tá vindo nula, o id não

Comment: Debugue também dentro do setter do seu Managed Bean para verificar se ele não está sendo chamado duas vezes, uma com o valor correto e outra com o valor nulo.

Comment: Se eu debugo no setter do tipoRelatoSelecionado ele vem null.

Comment: No p:selectOneMenu aparece a descrição do tipoRelato, que é String, mas ela não vai para o tipoRelatoSelecionado, apenas o id vai

Comment: Você não poderia comparar o Id ao invés da String?

Comment: Já tô fazendo isso, desisti de tentar pela string, mas eu não entendi bem o porque isso acontece. Se era pra ser assim mesmo, ou é bug

Comment: Irei revisar seu converter daqui a pouco, logo mais posto aqui

Comment: No seu selectOneMenu coloca o atributo immediate="true". Se funcionar eu explico quando eu chegar.

Comment: @Douglas, não deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobre a primeira questão:

> A descrição não está disponível no @ManagedBean

Avaliando o código do `TipoRelatoConverter`, de fato a descrição não está sendo utilizada:

```
Long id = Long.parseLong(string); 
TipoRelato tipoRelato = new TipoRelato();
tipoRelato.setIdTipoRelato(id);
```

Desta forma apenas o id do relato esta sendo passado para o objeto de retorno.

Para manter seu objeto todo você deverá mudar a implementação do seu converter para guardar ou buscar novamente o objeto convertido.

Neste [link](http://www.rponte.com.br/2008/07/26/entity-converters-pra-da-e-vender/) você pode verificar alguns exemplos de converters para manter a entidade toda. Outro exemplo sobre como buscar a entidade novamente podem ser vistas [neste post do BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343032/implement-converters-for-entities-with-java-generics&ved=2ahUKEwiysrPqt9LfAhXDUJAKHetDC3MQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3GzOM6kzVLCiwh8cc4-xJQ)

Acredito que a implementação do primeiro link é mais simples.

Desculpas pela demora, espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigada, consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que no seu `f:selectItems`falta o `itemValue`, ele é o atributo que vai ser atribuído na variavel `livroOrdemController.tipoRelatoSelecionado`, substitua por esse e acredito que funcionará:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{livroOrdemController.preencherComboTiposRelatos()}" var="itemTipoRelato" itemValue="#{itemTipoRelato}"/>
```

Comment: Fiz as alterações, mas continuou igual